# Allow only limited devices to cast (In context of chromecast)

Tags: chromecast

I know by design any devices connected on same Wifi network as Chromecast can cast.
Information available here: https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3006709?hl=en

But, is there anyway to overcome it and allow only limited devices (user) to cast? 
As doing so, opens up gates to different type of applications.
**e.g.** Apps for classroom, where students can connect to chromecast app and work on something in collaboration.

Any pointers will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

No, the only way you can currently do that is to have a wifi network dedicated to that class and only devices that you want to connect have the password to the network (i.e only those devices can get on that network). That can be achieved by connecting a simple/cheap router to your exiting network and set a password for tat wifi network, share that with your class and change the password for the next class if needed.